How to make a right ApplicationDbContext lifetime
when I'm executing a method, after making a external HttpClient request, my ApplicationDbContext lifetime ends, how to make this method right?
Method
    public async Task ConfirmEmail(int userId, Guid codeFromUser)
    {
        var user = _accountAccessor.GetUserById(userId);
        
        if (user.EmailConfirmed) throw new BadRequestException("Email already verified");

        // Getting Confirmation Code        
        var confirmationCode = await ResponseHelper.GetResponseAsync(_httpClientFactory, $"{ServiceUrlVariables.ConfirmationCodeApi}/GetCodeByUserId/{userId}");
        var confirmationCodeDto = await ResponseHelper.DeserializeResponseAsync<ConfirmationCodeDto>(confirmationCode);

        // validation
        if (confirmationCodeDto.ExpiresAt < DateTime.UtcNow) throw new BadRequestException("Code expired");
        if (confirmationCodeDto.Code != codeFromUser) throw new BadRequestException("Your code is wrong");
        
        // setting `EmailConfirmed == true`
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;
        _accountAccessor.UpdateUser(user);

        var codeId = confirmationCodeDto.Id;
        // Deleting ConfirmationCode from Db, cuz it's already verified
        await ResponseHelper.DeleteResponseAsync(_httpClientFactory, $"{ServiceUrlVariables.ConfirmationCodeApi}/DeleteConfirmationCodeById/{codeId}");
    }

ResponseHelper
// Get
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetResponseAsync(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, string requestUri)
    {
        using var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        
        return response;
    }

// Delete
    public static async Task DeleteResponseAsync(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, string requestUri)
    {
        using var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.DeleteAsync(requestUri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

Program
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(
    ConnectionStringsVariables.BookShopDB
));

I'm newbie and It's a bit hard for me to understand how to fix such a errors.
If my understanding is right, async request outlives the scope of my dbcontext

Based on your comments, I tried to reproduce your scenario and worked perfectly, here are the configs I used, you can check if there is something different that could lead you to the problem.
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Database=example;Username=user;Password=pwd"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ConfirmEmailService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

This is how I injected ConfirmEmailService. Here is the service
public class ConfirmEmailService
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public ConfirmEmailService(UserService userService, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task ConfirmEmailAsync(int userId, Guid codeFromUser, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var user = await _userService.GetUserById(userId, cancellationToken);
        
        if (user.EmailConfirmed) throw new Exception("Email already verified");

        // Getting Confirmation Code        
        var confirmationCode = await ResponseHelper.GetResponseAsync(_httpClientFactory, $"http://localhost:5151/code?userId={userId}");
        var confirmationCodeDto = await ResponseHelper.DeserializeResponseAsync<ConfirmationCodeDto>(confirmationCode);

        // validation
        if (confirmationCodeDto.ExpiresAt < DateTime.UtcNow) throw new Exception("Code expired");
        if (confirmationCodeDto.Code != codeFromUser) throw new Exception("Your code is wrong");
        
        // setting `EmailConfirmed == true`
        user.EmailConfirmed = true;
        await _userService.UpdateUser(user, cancellationToken);

        var userSaved = await _userService.GetUserById(userId, cancellationToken);

        if (userSaved.EmailConfirmed != true)
            throw new Exception("Not saved correctly");
        
        // var codeId = confirmationCodeDto.Id;
        // Deleting ConfirmationCode from Db, cuz it's already verified
        // await ResponseHelper.DeleteResponseAsync(_httpClientFactory, $"{ServiceUrlVariables.ConfirmationCodeApi}/DeleteConfirmationCodeById/{codeId}");
    }
}

So, explaining, basically I registered the context the same as you, that. By default it is registered as scoped service, as the definition states:

objects are the same for a given request but differ across each new
request

If you have awaited correctly for all your async calls, you should not have problems updating also the database afterwards.
More info about async programming.

ty for answer :)
as far as I understand, the problem is that I need to make this http request sync, cuz I need to get answer and after that move forward. How do you think?

Well, that shouldn't be a problem. You can have an async call and still continue after that.  Can I see how is your class ResponseHelper?

@Andrey341 I tried to simulate your scenario here and edited my answer with the findings. Check if it helps you.
